# Basic "empty" entity type?

Tags: 8, entities

Is there a module that provides an empty entity, to which I can add my own fields. I guess it would include just an Entity-ID as a primary field, and work with other entity modules.

For me, nodes have too much baggage included: title, nid, vid, publishing options, author and date.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check out the Console project.
https://www.drupal.org/project/console

It allows for command line creation of modules, and will generate entities for your module.

Here's a video explaining it all in 5 minutes.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agcqTEr5_48

navigate to the modules directory in the drupal root in your command line tool

enter command: bin/console generate:module enter the name for your module

enter a machine name for your module hit enter for the default path

enter a description hit enter for defaults for rest of questions

enter command: bin/console generate:entity:content

enter the name of the module you just created

enter a class name for the Entity you are creating

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll take a look. Be nice if there was GUI, though perhaps there is a good reason why not.

Comment: There is no GUI for entity creation in Drupal 8 that I am aware of.  The Entity Construction Kit that adds some UI for entity creation in D7 doesn't have a D8 release, and may be some time before it becomes available